# JSON only one row is printing

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Currently I'm preparing an AJAX response to give it out to the client. In this scenario (example), I have two `tuper` value rows in my database, but using this code, it only prints just 1 `tuper` value row.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project");

  $user = isset($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : '';
  $pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';


  function account($user, $pass)
  {
    global $con;
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM account WHERE   username='$user'");
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
        $x = array('Username'=> $row['username'],
                    'Password' => $row['password']);

        $accounts['Accounts'][]= $x;
        return json_encode($accounts);
    }

 }
 echo $acountList = account("tuper",$pass);

?>
```

Comment: You `return` *inside* the `while` loop, which means that it will never loop more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove that `return` inside the while loop. Create the array first, after its done, then return it.

```
function account($user, $pass)
{
    global $con;
    $data = array(); // setup container
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='$user'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $x = array(
            'Username'=> $row['username'],
            'Password' => $row['password']
        );

        $data[] = $x; // push inside the container
    }

    $accounts['Accounts'] = $data; // after the loop is done
    return json_encode($accounts); // then return it
}
```